# Extracting data from a text field holding JSON information

Tags: postgresql

I am new to JSON and PostgreSQL.
I have data like shown below. The movieGenres is a `TEXT` field.

**movieGenres**

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 2, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 2, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 8, 'name': 'Family'}]
```

I want to get the distinct list of genres from this list like

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Comedy'}
{'id': 6, 'name': 'Romance'}
{'id': 7, 'name': 'Adventure'}
```

There are multiple genres mapped to an ID in a single field  and I am trying to extract the unique Id and genre names from the "Genres" field in the above data. How do I do it in postgresql?

Comment: That's invalid JSON to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your data normalized like this:

```sql
select t.movieid, 
     (l ->> 'id')::integer as genre_id, l ->> 'name' as genre_name
from the_table t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(replace(genres, '''', '"')::jsonb) l;
```

And BTW field `genres` is not valid JSON, single quotes must be replaced with double quotes.

Comment: The genres is defined as a TEXT datatype and not JSON. I get the below error             
 ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb ->> double precision
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. How to resolve this

Comment: My omission, now edited, added quotes to 'id' and 'name'.

Comment: @NK1: you should be **valid** JSON  in a column defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`)